# How to redirect in .htaccess? => /whatever to /fr/whatever

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have my site www.site.com

First I would like to always have /fr/

I wrote this:

```
RewriteRule ^fr$ index.php?lang=fr [L]
```

Now I want on every links to be /fr/ required
For exemple www.site.com/fr/articleid works but I want www.site.com/articleid to be redirected to www.site.com/fr/articleid.

To sum up, I would like to do :

```
www.site.com => www.site.com/fr/

www.site.com/mypage => www.site.com/fr/mypage

www.site.com/whatever => www.site.com/fr/whatever 

www.site.com/fr/whatever => Nothing, it's good :)
```

Example :
If you go to http://www.deezer.com/blablabla you are automatically redirected to http://www.deezer.com/fr/blablabla (and then a 404 for blablabla)
Thanks !

Comment: So, what have you tried? Where is your code?

Comment: At the moment I have, RewriteRule ^(.+)/page$ pages/page1.php?lang=$1 [L] As you can see, if param lang is empty, 404 is showed

Comment: Ah, so there are more conditions you did not specify. You also want empty language codes to be recognized. And you get an error which you did not mention. Please include all details in your question. Edit it!

Comment: I suggest you read the excellent manual. It comes with valuable hints and good examples for all purposes. For example it explains in detail how to use rewrite logging using the two commands `RewriteLog` and `RewriteLogLevel`. That explains everything going on inside the rewriting engine in detail. Have a try! http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Answer (score -1):

For example

`RewriteRule ^en/ - [L]`

This will save for recursive rewrite

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /en/$1?%{QUERY_STRING} [L]`

This example will rewrite all urls

Comment: You must use the `QSA` flag, not `?%{QUERY_STRING}`

Comment: Did you add both lines? And try remove "?%{QUERY_STRING}" I don't sure now in correct syntax

Comment: Sorry, but you should only post an answers if you tested your answer.